# Упорядочить файлы и папки на рабочем столе

Tags: c#

Как программно упорядочить значки на рабочем столе в C#? Возможно ли это?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тут](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27487080/Sort-Desktop-Icons-Programmatically.html) задан точно такойже вопрос.

Вкратце:

Такое можно сделать, но средствами WinApi.

Для этого нужно воспользоваться `ArrangeIconicWindows`, если верить документации.

Comment: тут http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ArrangeIconicWindows.html и тут http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.GetDesktopWindow можно посмотреть как ими пользоваться из шарпа.